# Wasn't able to access structure members with arrow operator

Tags: c

I wasn't able to print the data inside the dynamically allocated memory of structure members with the arrow operator but I am able to put data into them with the same arrow operator

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int RollNo;
    char Name[15];
    int Class;
    int Marks;
    int Comments[100];
} details;

int main()
{
    int n, i, j;
    printf("Enter number of students\n");
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1) {
        perror("Invalid Input");
        return 1;
    }
    details *memptr = malloc(n * sizeof(details));
    if (memptr == NULL) {
        perror("Memory not allocated successfully!!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++, memptr++) {
        printf("Enter RollNo: ");
        scanf("%d%*c", &(memptr->RollNo));
        printf("Enter Name: ");
        fgets(memptr->Name, 15, stdin);
        printf("Enter Class: " );
        scanf("%d%*c", &(memptr->Class));
        printf("Enter Marks: ");
        scanf("%d%*c", &(memptr->Marks));
        printf("Enter Comments: ");
        fgets(memptr->Comments, 100, stdin);
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("Student details\n\n");
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++, memptr++) {
        printf("RollNo: %d ", memptr->RollNo);
        printf("Name: %s ", memptr->Name);
        printf("Class: %d ", memptr->Class);
        printf("Marks %d ", memptr->Marks);
        printf("Comments: %s\n", memptr->Comments);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Why am I unable to read the contents inside the dynamically allocated memory with arrow operator but I can able to put the data inside them with the same?

Comment: `memptr++` What do you think, where `memptr` points to after each of your loops?

Comment: (1) If you obtain a pointer from `malloc` and friends, you should store it intact for a subsequent call to `free` (which you forgot). Don't modify the only copy you have. (2) Prefer indexing over pointer arithmetic.

Answer (score 4):

You are moving your pointer to an invalid address.

```c
    for(i=0;i<n;i++,memptr++){
        printf("Enter RollNo: ");
        scanf("%d%*c",&(memptr->RollNo));
        ...
    }

    // Here, memptr points behind the last element of the allocated memory.
    // Any access behind that address is causing undefined behaviour.

    for(j=0;j<n;j++,memptr++){
        printf("RollNo: %d ",memptr->RollNo);
        ...
    }
```

Executing the program in a debugger and watching your pointers while stepping through the code should reveal that at once.

Modifying a pointer returned by a `*alloc` function is never a good idea.

Use your counter as index:

```c
    for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
        printf("Enter RollNo: ");
        scanf("%d%*c",&(memptr[j].RollNo));
        ...
    }

    for (j=0; j<n; j++) {
        printf("RollNo: %d ",memptr[j].RollNo);
        ...
    }
```

You can also copy `memptr` to a temporary variable and increment that variable. You must then reset that variable to initial value of `memptr` after your first loop.

BTW: You should also not mix `scanf` and `fgets` as it might confuse buffering.

Comment: Thank you Gerhardh for your back to back answer. So how to reset the variable to initial value of memptr after the first loop ?

Comment: You make a copy (`void *alloced_memory = memptr;`)  and after each(!) loop you assign back (`memptr = alloced_memory;`). But that is a waste of time. Just don't modify the originally allocated address. You must keep it for later when you need to free it, anyway.

Comment: We will be using arrow operator (->) to access structure members pointed by pointer right ?

Comment: If you really insist on moving the pointer instead of unsing an index, then you will use the arrow operator. If you want to make it more readable and less error prone, you would use the index as I have shown in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You increment them pointer to the allocated block, hence you lose the original value and the second loop keeps increasing this pointer past the end of the allocated array.

You should either use `memptr[i].xxx` instead of `memptr->xxx` and no longer increment the pointer or you should use a separate variable to use as a pointer.

Note also that `fgets(memptr->Name, 15, stdin);` will store the trailing newline in the `Name` array, provided the name is shorter than 14 characters and will leave extra characters in the input stream if a longer line has been typed.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int RollNo;
    char Name[15];
    int Class;
    int Marks;
    int Comments[100];
} details;

int main()
{
    int n, i, j;
    printf("Enter number of students\n");
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1) {
        perror("Invalid Input");
        return 1;
    }
    details *array = malloc(n * sizeof(*array));
    if (array == NULL) {
        perror("Memory not allocated successfully!!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    details *memptr;
    int status = 0;
    for (i = 0, memptr = array; i < n; i++, memptr++) {
        printf("Enter RollNo: ");
        if ((status = scanf("%d", &memptr->RollNo)) != 1)
            break;
        printf("Enter Name: ");
        if ((status = scanf(" %14[^\n]", memptr->Name)) != 1)
            break;
        printf("Enter Class: " );
        if ((status = scanf("%d", &memptr->Class)) != 1)
            break;
        printf("Enter Marks: ");
        if ((status = scanf("%d", &memptr->Marks)) != 1)
            break;
        printf("Enter Comments: ");
        if ((status = scanf(" %99[^\n]", memptr->Comments)) != 1)
            break;
        printf("\n");
    }
    if (status != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input\n");
        free(array);
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Student details\n\n");
    for (j = 0, memptr = array; j < n; j++, memptr++) {
        printf("RollNo: %d ", memptr->RollNo);
        printf("Name: %s ", memptr->Name);
        printf("Class: %d ", memptr->Class);
        printf("Marks %d ", memptr->Marks);
        printf("Comments: %s\n", memptr->Comments);
    }
    free(array);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It seems that your code missing `free()`.

Comment: @Tom: OOPS! used `fclose` instead of `free`! long time no sleep.

Comment: But fclose is close file. I always see you answer question. Pay attention to maintaining sufficient sleep in the body

Comment: @Tom: yes, I am a compulsive answerer, Visited 2859 days, 76 consecutive, 92% presence time since joining, such an addict :)

Comment: @Tom: of course the compiler would have spotted the `fclose()` mixup.

Comment: Does it need to change to `free(array)` in `if (status != 1)`?

Comment: @Tom: yes of course! done.

Comment: I think it is not very accurate that when xxx is array in your answer "use `&memptr[i].xxx` instead of `memptr->xxx`".

Comment: @Tom: indeed instances of `memptr->xxx` should be replaced with `memptr[i].xxx`

Answer (score 0):

You malloc memptr, but don't free memptr.

Here is my answer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Detail {
    int RollNo;
    char Name[100];
    int Class;
    int Marks;
    char Comments[100];
}details;

int main()
{
    int n,i,j,c,name;
    printf("Enter number of students\n");
    if(scanf("%d",&n)!=1){
        perror("Invalid Input");
        return 1;
    }
    details* memptr = malloc(n*sizeof(details));
    if(memptr==NULL){
        perror("Memory not allocated successfully!!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    memset(memptr, 0, n*sizeof(details));

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        int m = 0;
        int ak = 0;
        printf("***Total %d student, now first %dth student details\n", n, i+1);
        printf("Enter RollNo: ");
        scanf("%d",&(memptr[i].RollNo));
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Enter Name: ");
        name = getchar();
        memptr[i].Name[0] = name;
        for(ak = 0;ak < 99; ak++){
            if((name = getchar()) != '\n'){
                memptr[i].Name[ak] = name;
            }else{
                break;
            }
        }
        printf("Enter Class: " );
        scanf("%d",&(memptr[i].Class));
        printf("Enter Marks: ");
        scanf("%d",&(memptr[i].Marks));
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Enter Comments: ");
        c = getchar();
        memptr[i].Comments[0] = c;
        for(m = 0;m < 99; m++){
            if((c = getchar()) != '\n'){
                memptr[i].Comments[m] = c;
            }else{
                break;
            }
        }

        
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("Below is student details:\n");
    for(j=0;j<n;j++){
        printf("RollNo: %d ",memptr[j].RollNo);
        printf("Name: %s ",memptr[j].Name);
        printf("Class: %d ",memptr[j].Class);
        printf("Marks %d ",memptr[j].Marks);
        printf("Comments: %s\n",memptr[j].Comments);
    }
    free(memptr);
    memptr = NULL;
    return 0;
}
```

Run it will output:

```
Enter number of students
2
***Total 2 student, now first 1th student details
Enter RollNo: 1
Enter Name: john bob hi
Enter Class: 2
Enter Marks: 23
Enter Comments: He is good!!!

***Total 2 student, now first 2th student details
Enter RollNo: 2
Enter Name: jeff john hek
Enter Class: 1
Enter Marks: 11
Enter Comments: He is very bad!!!

Below is student details:
RollNo: 1 Name: john bob hi Class: 2 Marks 23 Comments: He is good!!!
RollNo: 2 Name: jeff john hek Class: 1 Marks 11 Comments: He is very bad!!!
```

Here is my other solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXSTRING 100

typedef struct Detail {
    int RollNo;
    char Name[100];
    int Class;
    int Marks;
    char Comments[100];
}details;

char* get_string(int* stringNum, int* status)
{
    int ak = 0;
    int c = 0;
    char* InputString = malloc(sizeof(char) * MAXSTRING);
    if(InputString == NULL){
        perror("Memory not allocated successfully!!\n");
    *status = 0;
        return NULL;
    }
    memset(InputString, 0, sizeof(char) * MAXSTRING);
    if(*stringNum > 99){
        printf("You want to input string is too long\n");
        *status  = 1;
        return NULL;
    }
    for(ak = 0;ak < MAXSTRING - 1; ak++){
        if((c = getchar()) != '\n'){
            InputString[ak] = c;
        }else{
            break;
        }
    }
    *status  = 2;
    return InputString;

}

int main()
{
    int n,i,j,temp,LengthName = 0, LengthComment = 0, statusNameOK = 0, statusCommentOK = 0;
    char* returnName = NULL;
    char* returnComment = NULL;
    printf("Enter number of students\n");
    if(scanf("%d",&n)!=1){
        perror("Invalid Input");
        return 1;
    }
    details* memptr = malloc(n*sizeof(details));
    if(memptr==NULL){
        perror("Memory not allocated successfully!!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    memset(memptr, 0, n*sizeof(details));

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        int m = 0;
        printf("***Total %d student, now first %dth student details\n", n, i+1);
        printf("Enter RollNo: ");
        scanf("%d",&(memptr[i].RollNo));
        fflush(stdin);
        temp = getchar();
        printf("Enter length of Name(max length is 100):");
        scanf("%d",&LengthName);    
        printf("Enter Name: ");
        temp = getchar();
        returnName = get_string(&LengthName, &statusNameOK);
        if(statusNameOK == 0){
            return -1;
        }
        while(returnName == NULL){
            printf("Enter length of Name(max length is 100():");
            scanf("%d",&LengthName);
            printf("Enter Name: ");
            returnName = get_string(&LengthName, &statusNameOK);
        }

        strncpy(memptr[i].Name, returnName, LengthName);
        free(returnName);
        returnName = NULL;

        printf("Enter Class: " );
        scanf("%d",&(memptr[i].Class));
        printf("Enter Marks: ");
        scanf("%d",&(memptr[i].Marks));
        fflush(stdin);
        temp = getchar();


        printf("Enter length of comment(max length is 100):");
        scanf("%d",&LengthComment); 
        printf("Enter comment: ");
        temp = getchar();
        returnComment = get_string(&LengthComment, &statusCommentOK);
        if(statusCommentOK == 0){
            return -1;
        }
        while(returnComment == NULL){
            printf("Enter length of comment(max length is 100():");
            scanf("%d",&LengthComment);
            printf("Enter comment: ");
            returnComment = get_string(&LengthComment, &statusCommentOK);

        }
        strncpy(memptr[i].Comments, returnComment, LengthComment);
        free(returnComment);
        returnComment = NULL;

        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("Below is student details:\n");
    for(j=0;j<n;j++){
        printf("RollNo: %d ",memptr[j].RollNo);
        printf("Name: %s ",memptr[j].Name);
        printf("Class: %d ",memptr[j].Class);
        printf("Marks %d ",memptr[j].Marks);
        printf("Comments: %s\n",memptr[j].Comments);
    }
    free(memptr);
    memptr = NULL;

    return 0;

}
```

Run it will output:

```
Enter number of students
2
***Total 2 student, now first 1th student details
Enter RollNo: 1
Enter length of Name(max length is 100):23
Enter Name: wf dsbdfs fnfg fgsn
Enter Class: 2
Enter Marks: 23
Enter length of comment(max length is 100):45
Enter comment: vdvdfbd  dfbdfsb fgsdb dfbssfdbdfsb dfbfdsbfdsgb

***Total 2 student, now first 2th student details
Enter RollNo: 3
Enter length of Name(max length is 100):34
Enter Name: dvd dbdfb dfgdfgfd dbdfb dfgdfg
Enter Class: 3
Enter Marks: 23
Enter length of comment(max length is 100):67
Enter comment: sdvvdv dsgvds dgdsagdafb!   

Below is student details:
RollNo: 1 Name: wf dsbdfs fnfg fgsn Class: 2 Marks 23 Comments: vdvdfbd  dfbdfsb fgsdb dfbssfdbdfsb dfbfdsbfd
RollNo: 3 Name: dvd dbdfb dfgdfgfd dbdfb dfgdfg Class: 3 Marks 23 Comments: sdvvdv dsgvds dgdsagdafb!
```

Comment: `scanf("%s",memptr[i].Comments);` Not gone be nice when the user wants to use up to 99 characters allowed for a "comment"... Comment: "Johnny could do better if he attended class."

Comment: @Fe2O3 As " BEFORE checking that memptr is not NULL", I see error, I have changed it.

Comment: @Fe2O3  As `scanf("%s",memptr[i].Comments);` I changed it to `scanf("%99s",memptr[i].Comments);`, what mean of "Comment: "Johnny could do better if he attended class.""

Comment: 1) Could use `calloc()` and ditch the `memset()` completely. 2) `scanf("%99s",memptr[i].Comments);` will still be satisfied at the first SP after the first _token_ found in the string... Maybe you want `" %[^\n]"`? (That leading SP in the format string should ditch any/all residual whitespace in the input buffer before starting to assign the string. (or so I've been told)... Q: "What mean of ..." A: Comments are usually not single words...

Comment: PS: You have "fixed" the entry of "Comments:"... But haven't "fixed" the entry of "Name:"...

Comment: @Fe2O3 How about my updated answer now?

Comment: Have you compiled and tested your current version? You wanna accept up to 99 characters into the 15 bytes allowed for `name`??? Seems you're overwriting the first character of both text fields with the second character... Are you writing an _answer_ or should you be posting this as a _question_? EDIT: Just saw you're mixing `getchar()` (in a loop) with `fgets()` a line or two below... What's this all about? Guessing???

Comment: Tom, Tom, Tom... `99` is a good limit for the `Comments[100]` array... However, `15` is NOT a good limit for the `Name[15]` array... This may _appear_ to work (because of structure padding to byte align the following struct member) but... An SO answer shouldn't need so much "micro criticism" to slowly migrate toward being somewhat better...

Comment: @Fe2O3 As save name, I changed 99 to 15. About I use getchar() to solve newline issue of input that I test if no getchar() reslut output will add newline to name. As for `fgets()` I don't use it, I comment it, but answer editor region have strange issue that let `fgets()` line cancel comment, from my code you can see that I don't use fgets.

Comment: @Fe2O3 I'm new to stackoverflow. I think I can learn something from criticism.

Comment: You need to learn (and practice) the basics of C coding, by yourself. We are ALL capable of making mistakes, but these haven't been simple human mistakes. These issues demonstrate that you do not have sufficient knowledge to be writing answers in this forum... Hang around and learn from questions and answers, by all means... Don't expect to be _tutored_ here, though.

Comment: Simple example: Why have you used _copy/paste_ in your answer to get both `Name` and `Comment` text fields... The correct solution would be to write a robust `get_string()` function that takes parameters and does validation of input... You gotta crawl before you can walk...

Comment: @Fe2O3 You are right, my English is poor that need to improve, thank you for your opinion.

Comment: @Fe2O3 `get_string()` that is a good idea.

Comment: @Fe2O3 I implement `get_string()` in my second solution.